# How to disable status bar and not hide it in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source, android-statusbar

I want to permanently disable status bar, not hide it. I was able to disable navigation bar by giving `qemu.hw.mainkeys=1` in system.prop and building the image.
But, i didn't find any method to disable status bar.  I even tried with the below flags -

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
```

But, these temporarily hide the status and navigation bar. If the user taps the screen, they pop back up. With these flags, they do not get fully disabled. There are many solutions online on how to hide the status and navigation bar, but not fully disable them.

**1)** The only method i found to disable status and navigation bar is by disabling systemui.

```
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

But i noticed that, disabling systemui, disables a lot of things , like SD card, volume, wallpapers,etc.

**2)** The other method that i tried is changing `status_bar_height` in `frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml` to **`0dp`** as shown below -

```
    <!-- Height of the status bar -->
    <dimen name="status_bar_height">@dimen/status_bar_height_portrait</dimen>
    <!-- Height of the status bar in portrait -->
    <dimen name="status_bar_height_portrait">0dp</dimen>
    <!-- Height of the status bar in landscape -->
    <dimen name="status_bar_height_landscape">@dimen/status_bar_height_portrait</dimen>
```

But, this caused the boot animation to not load and in-turn not to display the screen contents (My lvds went just dark).

How do i disable status bar?

Comment: I have used a similar solution to hide the status bar itself, the part where your display does not work, sounds a bit fishy, do you have any logs for that?

Comment: @RajatGupta: Sadly, I don't have the logs. I changed the build now ..

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to hide the status bar is by using this command

```
settings set secure user_setup_complete 0
```

You can enable it again by setting it to 1 or get the current status by using

```
settings get secure user_setup_complete
```

Another idea might be to use what you're using now to hide it but edit the swipe event function in source code for the status bar java class to do nothing so the swipe down gets ignored.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ```settings set secure user_setup_complete 0``` showed "unknown cmd set" .. I had to replace it with ```put``` , that is, ```settings put secure user_setup_complete 0``` . But, it still didn't hide/disable the status bar. 

I will check with hiding swipe event in status bar as you suggested.

Comment: You're right it's ```put```. I've just noticed it is still possible to bring the status bar up on certain screens in my application even if I disabled it. Please let me know if you find a solution to this.